# Mixpanel: distinct_id being set but events not recording against profile

Tags: mixpanel

I am setting the identity for a user when the user logs in

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   mixpanel.identify("<?php echo $name; ?>");
   mixpanel.track("Login");
</script>
```

When I look in the Live View, the event is being tracked and the correct distinct_id (i.e. the $name) is recorded against the event.

[image: Event]

When I look at the profile that matches the $name there is nothing tracked.

[image: Profile]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Mixpanel will link events and people based on the property called 'distinct_id'. Your call to identify in the javascript library is what is setting that property.

You should check to see if the profile you're looking at is related to the same distinct_id which will be shown in the url.